# Compose key in Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish

Tags: keyboard-layout, gnome-tweaks

I have been looking through the documentation for enabling the Compose key in Ubuntu, but the information from the [Ubuntu Community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) states that under Tweaks, that I should

"Click Disabled next to the Compose Key setting."

However, that button does not exist. There is no Compose Key setting in the version given by Ubuntu Jammy. I have done

sudo apt install gnome-tweaks

However, it does not have the Compose Key setting under Keyboard and Mouse. I also looked at Additional Layout Options, but I cannot find the relevant information.

[Additional Layout Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lWiR.png)

Any ideas on how to enable the compose key? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compose key control was dropped from Tweaks since it has been added to *Settings -> Keyboard*.

The wiki page you mention apparently needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

In 22.04 you'll find the setting here:

```
Settings -> Keyboard -> Options -> Position of Compose Key
```

Choosing the compose key is just a matter of checking one or more boxes.

My system was upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 using **apt dist-upgrade**, so still had the Compose Key set to **Right Alt**, but this wasn't working (typing right Alt would just activate the menus in whatever window had the focus). Clearing the checkbox and then resetting it again fixed that problem.

**Note:** Checking or unchecking one of these settings locked up parts of my window manager for about 5 seconds per modified checkbox, and when I clicked ahead a few settings, my entire window manager froze for a bit. Be patient.

*PS: Sorry I'm late to the party, but I'm posting for posterity. I might not be the only person who struggled for ages to find the Compose Key setting amid the blizzard of options in **Settings -> Keyboard**.*